# Restructure data from SQL base to Realtime Firebase

Tags: firebase, data-structures

I'm trying to set up a structure for my app moving from SQL structure to Firebase structure. At the moment I'm using the following:

```
-SQL-
  Product: {id, name, workPrice}
  Material: {id, name, unitCost}
  Product_Material{ pId, mId, amount}
```

I'm using a table to set the number of materials used so I can get an overall cost of the product.
I read about firebase structuring but I don't know how to apply to this case. What is recommended when associating the two would be the following:

```
-FB-
  Product: {
    boxId: { 
      name: "Wooden box"
      workPrice: "5"
      materials: {
         "woodId": true
      }
    }
  },
  Material: {
    woodId: {
      name: "wood",
      unitCost: "10"
    }
  }
```

But since I need an amount, it doesn't fit. How would this apply to my case? Do I need to make a third object the same as the third table in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Since Firebase is a No-SQL database, you can relation two objects by id's, for example, if a product has materials, you can reference the material id of that product, then you query for the product and get that material id, and with that material id, you go to the material node and lookup for that material.

Example

```
 Product: { 
    name: "Wooden box"
    workPrice: "5"
    materials: {
       "materialId": true,
       "materialId2": true
    }
  },
  Material: {
     materialId: {
    name: "wood",
    unitCost: "10"
     },
      materialId2: {
      name: "Plastic",
      unitCost:"15"
     }
  }
```

So, in this example, lets say you query the wooden box product, when you iterate over the materials sub node of product, you can get each material ID, and then you can relation those material id's with each product.

you can generate random materials ids with the `.push()` method in Realtime Database or `.add()` with Firestore

Comment: The thing is I don't just need to know the wooden box has the wood material , I need the amount, as the wooden box has X units of wood, which is not represented there and I don't know how to

Comment: You can merge/update the material id that contains wood with a new element that counts the wood that you setup in your client, or you can add random ids in materials with wood and use a reference like this - materials/wood/push1 , then you use this same reference but with push2 and so on, then use getChildrenCount() to count how many woods that box have